# Blazor IStringLocalizer for components with generic typeparam

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I try to give every component its own translation file, however when a component has a generic type in the class name the IStringLocalizer  does not find the localization files.

Component.razor

```
@typeparam T
<p>@L["Translate me"]</p>
```

Component.razor.cs

```
public sealed partial class Component<T>
{
    [Inject] private IStringLocalizer<Component<T>> L { get; set; } = default!;
    ....
}
```

Translation files with the name: `Component.resx` `Component.nl-NL.resx` exits with the sting that has to be translated.

Comment: What about having your components defined as `Component<T> : Component` (really bad naming - hopefully you are just obfuscating) then inject `IStringLocalizer<Component>` in the `Component` and you only do it once that way

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Thanks, the workaround in that question still works.

@MisterMagoo `Component` is indeed an obfuscated name. `IStringLocalizer<Component>` without <T> results in the compile error "requires 1 type argument".